# Gmail API Python - Retrieve Email Body

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail-api

In my Python Code, I would like to get the body of my Gmail emails. I want it to work with any email, independently of the format (plain text, Mime, etc) and text encoding.

From what I've seen, the only way to do that is to write a decoder able to handle any scenario. Before jumping into it, I have a couple questions:

1- Am I right about this, or is there a simpler way, from the API or a Python module, to get the body of any kind of email? (I'm all new to Python and Gmail API)

2- Has anybody already written such decoder that I could import into my code?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: you may want to brush up on [mcve] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

is a simple & quick sandbox case, you have to refactor some parts

```
import re
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import datetime
import string
import get_mail_search
from sys import stdout

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
class Get_mail(object):
    """docstring for Get_mail"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Get_mail, self).__init__()
        c=1
        self.login(c)
        self.toast_msg()

        raw_input()
    def toast_msg(self, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        M = self.mailbox()
        stdout.write("\n{}\n".format(get_mail_search.search_help_info))
        serach_input = raw_input()
        rv, data = M.search(None, serach_input)
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "No messages found!"
        id_ls = data[0].split()
        rev_id_ls = [i for i in reversed(id_ls)]
        if rev_id_ls:
            for o in rev_id_ls:
                try:
                    msg_content = self.process_mailbox(M, o)
                    _date_ = msg_content[0]
                    _from_ = msg_content[1]
                    _to_   = msg_content[2]
                    _subject_ = msg_content[3]
                    _msg_   = msg_content[4]
                    stdout.write("$$$$$$$$$$$\nDate: {}\nFrom: {}\nTo: {}\nSubject: {}\nMSG: {}\n".format(_date_,_from_,_to_,_subject_,_msg_))
                except Exception, e:
                    pass
        else:
            stdout.write("No {} Mail Found!".format(serach_input))
            raw_input()
            self.toast_msg()

    def login(self, try_c, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        try:
            stdout.write("\nMail:\n")
            mail = raw_input()
            if mail:
                M.login(str(mail), getpass.getpass())
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            if try_c<=3:
                stdout.write("Versuch: {}/3\n".format(try_c))
                stdout.write("Die eingegebene E-Mail-Adresse und das Passwort stimmen nicht uberein. Nochmal versuchen")
                try_c+=1
                self.login(try_c)
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
    def mailbox(self, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        rv, mailboxes = M.list()
        if rv == 'OK':
            for menu in mailboxes:
                print('{}'.format(menu))
            rv, data = M.select("inbox")
            if rv == 'OK':
                return M
    def eval_decode(self, header, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        return email.Header.decode_header(header)[0]

    def process_mailbox(self, M, num, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        rv, header = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
        header_msg = email.message_from_string(header[0][1])
        if header_msg.is_multipart():
            body=[payload.get_payload(decode=True) for payload in header_msg.get_payload()]
        else:
            body=payload.get_payload(decode=True)
        from_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['From'])
        subject_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['Subject'])
        date_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['Date'])
        to_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['To'])
        return (date_decode[0], from_decode[0], to_decode[0], subject_decode[0], str(body[0]))
def run():
    try:
        Get_mail()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        M.close()
        M.logout()
        sys.exit(1)
run()
```

Comment: I will work on it over the next few days and post my results here. I don't use IMAP to access my emails, but your process_mailbox function seems to be the solution to my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyways!